# Arduino: simple incrementing not working

Tags: arduino

A very simple code, but it has been killing me for the past 2 weeks.

Simply put: Button Up press increments State by 1. Button Down press decrements State by 1.

```
...

boolean ButtonPress;
const int PinUp = 3;   
const int PinDown = 2;  
int UpVal = 0;     
int DownVal = 0;   
int State = 0;

void setup()
{      
  pinMode(PinUp, INPUT);
  pinMode(PinDown, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  UpVal = digitalRead(PinUp);  
  DownVal = digitalRead(PinDown);

  if(DownVal == HIGH  && UpVal == LOW) 
  {
    lcd.clear();
    State++;
    ButtonPress = true;
  }
  if(UpVal == HIGH  && DownVal == LOW) 
  {
    lcd.clear();
    State--;
    ButtonPress = true;
  }
  if(ButtonPress == true)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
    lcd.print("State =  ");
    lcd.setCursor(18, 0);
    lcd.print(State);
  }
}
```

The problem is, the incrementing or decrementing jumps wildly to a seemingly random number.

If State is at 1 and I increment up, instead of getting 2, State can become anything upward such as 5 13 or 9. It's a random.

Similarly if I decrement from 1, instead of getting 0, State can become anything downward such as -6 -2 or - 10. This is random as well.

The only major part of the code I did not include was the means of outputting onto my 20, 4 LCD.

What is wrong here?

Comment: are you calling "loop" in a loop?

Comment: I don't think so. At least that's not the intent. void loop is the only intended loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information about your setup but this looks like a common problem to do with button bouncing. The physical button when pressed will cause the signal on the pin to bounce (the voltage to jump up and down.) There are various ways of dealing with this. Try reading this [article](http://tinymicros.com/mediawiki/images/8/8a/Jack_Ganssel_Guide_To_Debouncing.pdf) on switch debouncing for a better understanding.

You can debounce both in software and hardware. As a simple test, I bet if you slow down your loop, it will be more stable.

Comment: Shoot you're right! about the slowing down part. I needed a delay! I removed the button and tested with wire tapping. the longer the wire was on, the higher the number! I'll definitely have to look into the bouncing though. Haven't messed with HID's since college and it completely left my mind as a possibility. Thank you!

Comment: @Jackson Here there is a much bigger problem: read my answer to get more infos about

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you want to trigger the state change on the FALLING edge of the button, not when the button is LOW.

In your case, when the loop function "loops" and you are still holding down the button it will increment/decrement again the value. This is not what you want.

Consequently you want to look for the falling edge of the transition. You should save the old state and then compare it to the current one:

```
byte UpVal = 0;
byte oldUpVal = 0;
byte DownVal = 0;
byte oldDownVal = 0;

void loop()
{
  UpVal = digitalRead(PinUp);  
  DownVal = digitalRead(PinDown);

  if(DownVal == HIGH && oldUpVal == HIGH && UpVal == LOW) 
  {
    lcd.clear();
    State++;
    ButtonPress = true;
  }
  if(UpVal == HIGH && oldDownVal == HIGH && DownVal == LOW) 
  {
    lcd.clear();
    State--;
    ButtonPress = true;
  }
  oldUpVal = UpVal;
  oldDownVal = DownVal;
  ...
```

(by the way, please, use 8-bit variables - i.e. bytes - instead of 16-bit ones - i.e. ints).

Now, once you fixed this, you will notice that usually you will get "bouncy" contacts (i.e. you will get a couple of increments every time). Search on google to understand what is debouncing and why it is needed.

For your application, however, I suggest you to use the Bounce2 library, which is really easy to use. See [the page on the Arduino website](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Bounce) to get to the download links and how to install it.

Anyway, for your problem, this can be the code

```
#include <Bounce2.h>

byte oldUpVal = 0;
byte oldDownVal = 0;
Bounce debouncerUp = Bounce();
Bounce debouncerDown = Bounce();

void setup() {
  pinMode(PinUp,INPUT);
  pinMode(PinDown,INPUT);

  debouncerUp.attach(PinUp);
  debouncerUp.interval(5);
  debouncerDown.attach(PinDown);
  debouncerDown.interval(5);

  ...
}

void loop()
{
  debouncerUp.update();
  debouncerDown.update();

  if(debouncerDown.read() == HIGH && oldUpVal == HIGH && debouncerUp.read() == LOW) 
  {
    lcd.clear();
    State++;
    ButtonPress = true;
  }
  if(debouncerUp.read() == HIGH && oldDownVal == HIGH && debouncerDown.read() == LOW) 
  {
    lcd.clear();
    State--;
    ButtonPress = true;
  }
  oldUpVal = debouncerUp.read();
  oldDownVal = debouncerDown.read();
  ...
```

Note that now you don't need `UpVal` and `DownVal`, since the reading function is done in the `update` (so the `read` function does not actually read the inputs).

Just one remark: you know that you need a pullup on the board, don't you? If you didn't mount a pullup, you can just convert `pinMode(xxxx,INPUT);` in `pinMode(xxxx,INPUT_PULLUP);`.